# how can I reach the id?

Tags: python-3.x

I just started to work with telegram API in python and telegram returned this to me

```
{'ok': True, 'result': [{'update_id': 565003056, 'message': {'message_id': 3, 'from': {'id': 137505406, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Taha', 'username': 'thkh1998', 'language_code': 'fa'}, 'chat': {'id': 137505406, 'first_name': 'Taha', 'username': 'thkh1998', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1549632520, 'text': '/start', 'entities': [{'offset': 0, 'length': 6, 'type': 'bot_command'}]}}]}
```

as it is in here I used `.json()` on the output so here is my problem I can't reach the id 137505406

I have tried to reach it with `answer['result']['chat']['id']` but I faced this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Look closely. `answer['result']` is not a dictionary.

Comment: answer['result] is an array. chat is in under message

Answer (score 1):

For a deeply nested structure like this, it can help if you work with it step by step in an interactive Python shell.

Assign your response to a variable and slowly work your way towards the desired value.

```
>>> json = {'ok': True, 'result': [{'update_id': 565003056, 'message': {'message_id': 3, 'from': {'id': 137505406, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Taha', 'username': 'thkh1998', 'language_code': 'fa'}, 'chat': {'id': 137505406, 'first_name': 'Taha', 'username': 'thkh1998', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1549632520, 'text': '/start', 'entities': [{'offset': 0, 'length': 6, 'type': 'bot_command'}]}}]}
>>> json['result']
[{'update_id': 565003056, 'message': {'message_id': 3, 'from': {'id': 137505406, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Taha', 'username': 'thkh1998', 'language_code': 'fa'}, 'chat': {'id': 137505406, 'first_name': 'Taha', 'username': 'thkh1998', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1549632520, 'text': '/start', 'entities': [{'offset': 0, 'length': 6, 'type': 'bot_command'}]}}]
>>> json['result'][0]
{'update_id': 565003056, 'message': {'message_id': 3, 'from': {'id': 137505406, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Taha', 'username': 'thkh1998', 'language_code': 'fa'}, 'chat': {'id': 137505406, 'first_name': 'Taha', 'username': 'thkh1998', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1549632520, 'text': '/start', 'entities': [{'offset': 0, 'length': 6, 'type': 'bot_command'}]}}
>>> json['result'][0]['message']
{'message_id': 3, 'from': {'id': 137505406, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Taha', 'username': 'thkh1998', 'language_code': 'fa'}, 'chat': {'id': 137505406, 'first_name': 'Taha', 'username': 'thkh1998', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1549632520, 'text': '/start', 'entities': [{'offset': 0, 'length': 6, 'type': 'bot_command'}]}
>>> json['result'][0]['message']['chat']
{'id': 137505406, 'first_name': 'Taha', 'username': 'thkh1998', 'type': 'private'}
>>> json['result'][0]['message']['chat']['id']
137505406
```

You're missing two levels of nesting in the provided code. You need

```
answer['result'][0]['message']['chat']['id']
```